# I want animate scrollleft += a variable but i cant seem to make it work without a specific number

Tags: javascript, jquery

pls help.

right now I have a button that scrolls a div 500 and sets the current position to 500. I need to replace the 500 by a variable number. so += a variable number. Any help would be much appreciated.

```
$('#button').click(function() {
  $('#row_01').animate({
    scrollLeft: '+=500'
  }, 1000);
});

$('#button_alt').click(function() {
  $('#row_01').animate({
    scrollLeft: '-=500'
  }, 1000);
});
```

I want to scroll the div a percentage distance on click.

Comment: I want to scroll the div a percentage distance on click using a variable

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried concatenation via **'+=' + increment**?

```
const increment = "10%";
$('#button').click(function() {
  $('#row_01').animate({
    scrollLeft: '+=' + increment
  }, 1000);
});

$('#button_alt').click(function() {
  $('#row_01').animate({
    scrollLeft: '-=' + increment
  }, 1000);
});
```

Comment: Maybe it’s obvious I’m new to this. Thanks so much for ur help